# Get items which datetime custom field is greater than specified value using Search Query Builder

Tags: sxa, querybuilder

I am trying to create query using Search Query builder (used to create new Item Query in SXA site) that will return items where custom datetime field value is in defined range.

I can see that there is a "Search by a field value" option:

[image]

Also based on documentation creating range should be possible but onlt for numerical and text values:
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/searching/build_a_search_query#_Search_within_a

I have tried the query but no results are coming:
[image]

Without the Start Time condition defined I can see all items that are available. I just want the ones which are greater than specified date time.

### Questions:

Is it possible to use same range as specified in documentation above also for datetime values? What should be correct format of values in this case to make it working?

Can I apply some greater-than and less-than notation here?